# How to run Geb TestCases from windows command line?

Tags: java, junit, spock, geb

I want to be able to run the geb testcases(SampleTestCase.groovy) from windows command line?

I am having a hard time doing so, can anyone please help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Is Gradle your build tool? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

gradlew  ''moduleName':test --tests *'fullSpecWithpackage'